# How to keep custom dialog design when softinputmode change like keyboard open/close?

Tags: android, dialog, android-constraintlayout, window-soft-input-mode

I have designed custom dialog with the help of `ConstraintLayout` and `EditText` using `DialogFragment` in android. It is working fine. But issue only with Android version 11. When I open the dialog look fine but when keyboard open and close. View suddenly move to right side.

I have also tried with different type of layout `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`, but still facing the same problem.

Also tried to with different type of SoftInputMode `adjustPan`, `adjustResize`, `adjustNothing`, `stateHidden` and so on, but result is same.

my designed xml layout is look like.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clBirthWeight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_container_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/white_child_container_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/screen_container_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBirthWeight"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/birth_weight"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/birth_weight"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birth_weight"
            style="@style/Theme.EZazi.EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/enter_birth_weight"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/apgar_1min"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_space"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvBirthWeight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/obs_input_min_width"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clApgar1Min"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_container_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/white_child_container_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/screen_container_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clBirthWeight">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvApgar1Min"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/apgar_1min"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/apgar_1min"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/apgar_1min"
            style="@style/Theme.EZazi.EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/enter_apgar_at_1_min"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/apgar_5min"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_space"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvApgar1Min"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/obs_input_min_width" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clApgar5Min"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_container_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/white_child_container_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/screen_container_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clApgar1Min">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvApgar5Min"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/apgar_5min"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/apgar_5min"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/apgar_5min"
            style="@style/Theme.EZazi.EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/enter_apgar_at_5_min"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/sex"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_space"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvApgar5Min"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/obs_input_min_width" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clBabySex"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_container_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/white_child_container_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/screen_container_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clApgar5Min">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBabySex"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sex"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sex"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sex"
            style="@style/Theme.EZazi.EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/enter_sex_of_baby"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/baby_status"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_space"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvBabySex"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/obs_input_min_width" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clBabyStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_container_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/white_child_container_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/screen_container_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clBabySex">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBabyStatus"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/baby_status"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/baby_status"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/baby_status"
            style="@style/Theme.EZazi.EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/enter_baby_status"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/mother_status"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_space"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvBabyStatus"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/obs_input_min_width" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clMotherStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_container_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/white_child_container_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/screen_container_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clBabyStatus">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMotherStatus"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mother_status"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/mother_status"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mother_status"
            style="@style/Theme.EZazi.EditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/enter_mother_status"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_space"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvMotherStatus"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/obs_input_min_width" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can see in the below attached video what kind of issue I am facing with softinputmode.

[image: Issue with keyboard open and close]

Tried so hard with multiple solutions, but still the same.

I will be thankful to you for your help and solution.

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: Hi @Sidnio thanks for your comment, but with wrap_content also not working

Comment: Can you provide the GitHub source code?

Comment: Hi @Sidnio here you can found the source in master branch https://github.com/mithunvaghela/CustomDialogDemo, added all dialog related code inside the repository, This issue only I faced in Android 11, Current project has mobile and tablet support so can't set static width for input. Thanks

Comment: 1,You can specify different values  2，dialog sets the width and height  3，You can reset the layout such as LinearLayout

Comment: LinearLayout      android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: Hi @Sidnio thanks for suggesting, replaced from constraintlayout to linearlayout, now it working fine in Android 11 and other version also.